# Evaluate the following:

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the value of ?

$\cos\left(\pi \times \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

How would you evaluate it?

Reference: I was solving a question and in the calculation, I had to put the value of $\cos\left(\pi \times \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ to get to the final result.

The question is :

If a particle is moving with velocity $v(t) = \sin(\pi t)$ along a straight line such that $s\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 5$ , then its position function is given by:

The solution provided in the book is
$(-\frac{1}{\pi}\cos(\pi t) + \frac{1}{\pi} + 5)$

Now to obtain this solution, value of
$\cos\left(\pi \times \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is kept as 1. How can it be 1? Is the value rounded off to 1 or is it exactly 1?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Probably an error in the book.  Perhaps the initial condition should have been $s(1)=5$.